# Strange: google indexing onload generated content?

Tags: angularjs, seo, angularjs-directive

I've noticed in google's results page that my website's listing details (i.e. bellow the link) displays content that is only generated during the page onload function. This surprised me as I thought google does not index JS generated content. Later I came across [this post](http://rogeralsing.com/2013/08/11/angularjs-and-seo-part-2/) showing a way to create title and meta-description tags using angularjs directives (which are only interpreted during onload)! So does this actually work? I would also appreciate some reference if it does and google indeed indexes the page after running its onload. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and has already been [cross-posted at Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/strange-google-indexing-onload-generated-content)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Google doesn't wait for onload (are you sure this data isn't available in the HTML itself?)

From reading the post you linked there and the previous one it appears the author explains in the first post that his company developed a free service to give you a loaded "snapshot" of your site that you can then setup a redirect to.  In that scenario any AngularJS will work fine though hence the directives for title/metadata in the second post.

http://rogeralsing.com/2013/08/11/angularjs-and-seo-part-1/

I believe the only real way to get SEO that is as up to date as possible is to use PhantomJS to load your pages when the hash bang #! URL is found by a search engine.

Comment: As for the listing details only being generated during onload: very sure. As for the snapshot - thanks. I found the post directly from google :-).

Comment: BTW @shaunhusain is the html5 history api a good alternative to the hash-bang method?

Comment: unsure of the relationship sorry :|